# FLASK/PYTHON - Add strikethrough styling to todo list item in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have a todo list where I can toggle an item (title) complete/not complete. I want to add a strikethrough when I click the update button to mark the item complete. I am happy to just wrap it in  tag in the DB then render that on my page afterwards

The below is my attempt, I can get as far as clicking the button and wrapping the item in  but I can't toggle between true/false to remove the  tags it just keeps adding them.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, current_app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app

todoapp = Blueprint("todoapp", __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)

@todoapp.route("/update/<int:todo_id>")
def update(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).first()
    todo.complete = not todo.complete #toggle true/false for complete
    if todo.complete == False:
        todo.title = "<del>" + todo.title + "</del>" # add strikethrough tags to title
        db.session.commit()
    else
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(request.referrer)
```

**html**

```
  {% for todo in todo_list %}
  <div class="ui segment">
      <p class=""ui big header"> {{todo.id}} | {{todo.title}}</p>
      {% if todo.complete == False %}
      <span class="ui grey label"> Not Completed </span>
      {% else %}
      <span class="ui green label"> Completed </span>
      {% endif %}
      <a class = "ui blue button" href="/admin/update/{{ todo.id }}">Update</a>
  </div>
  {%endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Do not use the `filter_by(id=todo_id).first()` use the `get(todo_id)`

2 - the if statement is incomplete

```py
if not todo.complete:
    todo.title = "<del>" + todo.title + "</del>" # add strikethrough tags to title
    db.session.commit()
else:
    # remove the <del> tag
    db.session.commit()
```

3 - You should not do this, add the  tag in the html

```html
<p class=""ui big header"> {{todo.id}} |

{% if not todo.complete %}
<del>
{% endif %}

{{todo.title}}

{% if not todo.complete %}
</del>
{% endif %}

</p>
```

this is not the best way to do this, I recommend you to get from the database and later process the result to the html, and do not update the title with tags when it is marked as not completed.